# evaluate the limit or show that it doesn't exist

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the limit or prove that it doesn't exist .
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{\sin(2x) -2x + y}{x^3 + y} $$

Comment: Consider approaching $(0,0)$ on the line $x=0$. Then the limit (if it exists by uniqueness) goes to $1$. Now, consider the line $y=0$. Then $\lim \frac{sin(2x)-2x}{x^3} = \lim \frac{2cos(2x) - 2}{3x^2} = \lim \frac{-4sin(2x)}{6x} = \lim \frac{-8cos(2x)}{6} = -4/3$. This is nothing more than repeated use of l'Hopital's Rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the sequence $(0,1/n)$. The limit along this sequence is $1$.

Now look at the sequence $(1/n,0)$. The limit along this sequence is $-4/3$ (Look at Taylor series expansion of sin for instance).

So, limit doesn't exist.

Comment: The second limit should go to $-4/3$. It is clearly negative as $\sin(x) < x$ for $x > 0$ and $\sin(x) > x$ for $x < 0$.

Comment: @ChrisK: Thanks- you are right :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If the limit it exists, it exists along the line $y=x$ and it coincides with the limit along the curve $y=x^3$. Recall that $\sin(a)\sim_0a$.